# MySQL Query - randomly select row with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table in database, please refer to the link below.
What I need is random select one row in table question which not stated in table answered, and it should be done in one query. 
Anyone know how to write this query?

- relationship: question.id = answered.question_id

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE question.id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answered)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

This query will randomly select a question which is not answered.

Result:

```
ID  TITLE
3   Why do you want this job?
```

See example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15f7d/1)